# jQuery objects as elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I see this syntax in some advanced jQuery:

```
$container
```

as in:

```
$input = $container.find('.fn_this_timeline')
```

EDIT: based on some of the comments below, just to clarify the first instance of '$container' that I can see is created right at the beginning:

```
init: function($container){
var myThing = this,
$input = $container.find('.fn_do_some_calc'),
$submit = $container.find('.fn_do_some_other_calc'),
defaultValue = parseInt($input.val(), 10);

myThing.$container = $container;
```

The line above confuses me even more :/

I'm used to using jQuery selectors like this: $('#mySelector').method('etc');

Can someone let me know what the difference is and when it's appropriate or applicable to use the 'shorthand' style?

Comment: is `$container` just storing a jQuery object? Somewhere is there a `$container = $('#container')`?

Comment: Troy, see the edit above. It doesn't appear to be as straightforward as that.

Comment: @hyperdouche `myThing.$container = $container;` is totally different. It's saying that the "$container" property (yes, objects can have property names that start with `$` of the `myThing` object should be set as the `$container` variable (jQuery object).

Comment: @hyperdouche see my answer below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't some shorthand, this is just the use of Javascript variables. For example, the `$container` variable was probably declared like this:

```
var $container = $("#container");
```

Because it's stored, the element (jQuery object) is "cached" and can be reused without having jQuery go out and re-traverse the DOM to find it again (because it has to every time `$("select")` is used).

The use of `$` at the beginning of the variable name is sometimes helpful for the developer to remember that it holds a jQuery object and not a Javascript element (like what's returned from `document.getElementById("container");`.

Depending on where your question's `init` method is, the line `myThing.$container = $container;` is just setting an object's property "$container" as the value of the `$container` variable. So the object is probably like:

```
var myObject = {
    init: function () {
        // blah blah blah
    },

    $container: undefined
};
```

And after running the `init` method, it will set the "$container" property to something.

Comment: Yes, the idea of cacheing makes sense. I just still don't know when I can use this way or use the way I'm used to. Thanks for your answer

Comment: @hyperdouche You can use this way whenever you want to. The reason why you'd want to use this way is really only for caching. If you ever have to use the same element (selector) multiple times (for any reason - manipulating it later, passing it to a function, etc.), it's much more efficient to store its result once. So if you need to hide the element with an id "asdf", then hide the element with an id "fdsa" but later do something else with it, you'd use `$("#asdf").hide(); var $fdsa = $("#fdsa").hide(); $fdsa.whatever();`

Comment: Thanks for the extra clarification.

Comment: As a rule of thumb: If you use a selection `$(".something")` more than once, you should cache it.

Comment: @JonnySooter Haha that's what I was trying to say, I just keep rambling. Very well, simply put. I think it's important to add that you should cache it **in the same scope**. Out of scope caching may be fine/work, but may not be the right approach

Answer (score 1):

This is just to make clear, that the `$container` variable is already a wrapped jQuery object, instead of e.g. a native DOM node.

For Example you can write:

```
var container  = document.getElementById('item');
var $container = jQuery(container); // or:
var $container = jQuery('#item');
```

Got the point?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, yes it is shorthand.

For the function you noted:

```
init: function($container){
var myThing = this,
$input = $container.find('.fn_do_some_calc'),
$submit = $container.find('.fn_do_some_other_calc'),
defaultValue = parseInt($input.val(), 10);
```

The $ is included so you know to pass a jQuery object into the function. So When you call it, you may do something like this:

```
init($('#theid'));
```

As far as the line below:

```
myThing.$container = $container;
```

That is just storing your jQuery object as part of your myThing object. One other note, you could do something like `$var = 1` and that would be perfectly valid. However usually it is done as a reminder to store a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

There is no shortcut method for using jQuery.

It is Standard Method to declare variable in jQuery.

i.e $container = $("#container");

$container is a jquery object.

Understanding: $ indicate that it is jquery object so apply operation on it as appropriate.